# FCM notification not receiving when my aap is closeed

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on FCM notification, notificaion receiving in background and foreground but not receiving when my application is closed.
I Installed `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base` Version `117.6.0`, `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` Version `121.1.0` pakages and also using `Xamarin.Forms` Version `5.0.0.2012`.
I also download `google-services.json` and set Build Action is `GoogleServicesJson`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.packagename" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
  <application android:label="Demo App" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <permission android:name="com.packagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.packagename.C2D_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

**and i added service inside Appication Tag  in Android Manifest for test but not working**

```
<service android:name="com.rajhansfeedback.MyFirebaseIIDService" android:stopWithTask="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
</service>
```

This is my MainActivity.cs Class

```
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        static readonly string TAG = "MainActivity";
        internal static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "my_notification_channel";
        internal static readonly int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
                    
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (Intent.Extras != null)
            {
                foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
                {
                    var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                    Log.Debug(TAG, "Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, value);
                }
            }

            IsPlayServicesAvailable();
            CreateNotificationChannel();

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        public bool IsPlayServicesAvailable()
        {
            int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.Success)
            {
                if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsUserResolvableError(resultCode))
                {}
                else
                {
                    Finish();
                }
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
                // support library). There is no need to create a notification
                // channel on older versions of Android.
                return;
            }

            var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                                                  "FCM Notifications",
                                                  NotificationImportance.Default)
            {

                Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
            };

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.NotificationService);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
```

This is my service class MyFirebaseIIDService.cs

```
[Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
        public override void OnNewToken(string p0)
        {
            base.OnNewToken(p0);
            SendRegistrationToServer(p0);
        }
        void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
        {
            // Add custom implementation, as needed.
        }
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage p0)
        {
            base.OnMessageReceived(p0);
            var body = p0.Data["body"];
            var title = p0.Data["title"];
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + body);
            SendNotification(title, body, p0.Data);
        }

        void SendNotification(string title, string messageBody, IDictionary<string, string> data)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            intent.PutExtra("body", messageBody);
            intent.PutExtra("title", title);

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this,
                                                          MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID,
                                                          intent,
                                                          PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                                      .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.logo)
                                      .SetContentTitle(title)
                                      .SetContentText(messageBody)
                                      .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                      .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
    }
```

Please guys guide me where i am doing mistake

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not expert enough to help on this. Have you looked at similar stackoverflow questions? Google `fcm notification not received when app closed site:stackoverflow.com` - that lists at least 10 similar questions. What instructions did you follow to make this? Maybe there is a tutorial with sample app you can download and build, to see a working example?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i am working last 2 days on this issue, and tring many forums answers but nothing happened

Comment: Sorry, my only suggestion is to download one of these githubs - google `github firebase fcm notification android sample app`.  See if any of them have code to handle app closed, then try to get that one to build and run.  Should be easier if start with an example that works.  And if can't get to work, then try contacting author of that sample. Look for a sample that has been updated fairly recently, if possible.